# How do I get brightness control working on an HP 655?

Tags: brightness

please I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my hp 655 alongside windows 8.1 but my brightness control doesn't work although it does work on my windows platform.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my brightness feature to work.
I discovered that my device uses radeon_bl0:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

to check and then i navigated to the brightness file under radeon_bl0.
My maximum brightness was 255 of which my current settings was on and i changed the value to a much lesser value and there, it worked. Here is the code i used...

```
 echo 'value' > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

where 'value' is any value between 1 and 255.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying GRUB configuration (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) and use:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

instead of:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Then reboot your computer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but on my grub.cfg file i couldn't find the above line.

Comment: @OROBOGENIUS and anything that says `quiet splash`? Sometimes people just insert that as a parameter for loading the kernel. Add `acpi_osi=Linux` just after `quiet splash` in the kernel parameters and try. Remember that you can always **test** without modifying `grub.cfg` by editing boot parameters on GRUB load (letter `e` or something). Also, in Ubuntu you could try editing the file `/etc/default/grub` as well (maybe there is the line I mentioned).

Comment: Doesn't work on HP 633 with Xubuntu 16.04.3 and kernel 4.13.

Comment: Why the downvote **four years after**?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe, it could be the solution:
Add `video.use_native_backlight=1` in the grub

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And add:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1"
```

Then update the grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, reboot.

Comment: What will updating GRUB have to do with brightness?

Comment: @Tim in some cases kernel parameters have to be set. Though I'd like a bit more explanation as well.

Comment: Well... the kernel actually manages the ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface), which has to manage, well... the power interface and devices that consume energy (like the backlight). The ACPI acts as an interface to call and set backlight parameters in this case. Of course, there are many types of ACPI implementations (some standard, other not-so-standard) and this is clearly one that needs to be set manually (a not-so-standard ACPI implementation which requires "different" kernel extensions). That's what I understand at least...

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs but the problem still persist. Here is the problem in detail. The brightness toggle actually works but it doesn't have any effect on the display, that is it doesn't dim or increase its just there. Like my windows 8.1 when i had the same problem i just installed an AMD Graphics driver and then it worked but am not sure about ubuntu. And i have tried editing the grub with the settings you guys posted above but still no solution.

Comment: Just tested it on HP 655 with Xubuntu 16.04.3 with kernel 4.13. Doesn't work.